# Override rejected item to approved

Tags: list-item, approval

An item list was accidentally rejected instead of approved. Is it possible to override a rejected list item to approved? If so, how?

Answer (score 2):

You haven't specified much details. Based on your basic information, I am providing my approach.

You can always change the status of the item from `Approved` to `Rejected` and from `Rejected` to `Approved`.

Just follow the same steps which you followed for Rejecting the item.

Select `Approved` and save the status.

The status of item will be changed again to `Approved`